# Trouble Finishing Supremum Proof

Tags: calculus, real-analysis

**Problem:** Prove that if $a$ is an upper bound for $A$, and if $a$ is also an element of $A$, then it must be that $a=\sup A$.

**This is what I have so far:** Let $a\in A$ such that $a$ is an upper bound for $A$. In order to prove $a=\text{sup} A$ we must prove $a$ is an upper bound for A and if $b$ is an upper bound for $A$, then $b\geq a$. By our assumption, the first part is true. Now, let $b$ be an upper bound for A.

**I am having trouble finishing the proof from here. These are new concepts that I am studying. Any help is appreciated. **

Comment: You've assumed $b$ is an upper bound for $A$. But where does $a$ live?

Comment: it is stated that $a$ is in the set $A$ @AdrianKeister

Comment: Exactly! So what does that imply?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Suppose that $b \leq a$. But recall that $a$ is an element of $A$. So how can both $b \leq a$ and $b$ be an upper bound for $a$?

Comment: im sorry, can you explain what you did?

Comment: I see now that this is exactly the same thought process as Adrian Keister was mentioning in the comments. So we did the same thing. Do you see how both the comment chain and this answer complete the problem?

Comment: no i am having trouble understanding

Comment: im guessing you're trying to arrive at a contradiction?

Comment: Yes, this is for a proof by contradiction

Comment: so i am letting $b$ be an upper bound for $A$ in my proof...this would imply that $b\geq a$ wouldn't it?

Comment: That would, yes.

Comment: so using your statement for a contradiction just further proves that $b$ must be greater than or equal to $a$ and $b$ is an upper bound therefore $a=\text{sup} A$?

Comment: That's the big idea. It sounds like you're starting to get your head around it.

Comment: thank you so much for working through this with me

Answer (score 1):

Let $s=\sup A$

Let $a$ be an upper bound of $A$

Then if $a \in A$ then $a \leq s$ because $s$ is also an upper bound of $A$

Also $s \leq a$ because $s$ is the $\text{least}$ upper bound of $A$

Thus $s=a$

Answer (score 0):

The supremum of $A$ is the *least upper bound*.

Suppose $b$ is an upper bound of $A$. Then $a\le b$. So $a$ is an upper bound that's less than every other upper bound, which is the same as saying it's the least upper bound.

---

You may want to see it with a different characterization/definition of supremum. The number $s$ is a supremum for $A$ if

1. $x\le s$, for every $x\in A$
2. for every $\varepsilon>0$, there exists $y\in A$ such that $s-\varepsilon<y$

Now conditions 1 and 2 are satisfied in your case for $s=a$; for 2, take $y=a$.